# Single Word for "Clip-Clopping" Sound

Tags: single-word-requests

> The clip-clopping of the businessman's footsteps against the linoleum floor echoed down the hallway.

Is there a better word I can substitute for "clip-clopping" here?

Comment: Why are you dissatisfied with *clip-clopping* here?  To my ear, it sounds fine; without knowing what specific aspects you’d like to improve, it’s hard to suggest a better alternative.

Comment: Hopefully this is helpful ... in my experience linoleum really flattens noises, a surface like stone tile or concrete might be more appropriate. Sorry if this is useless!

Comment: Clip clop requires a sort of hollowness that you wouldn't get from a woman's shoe or from a workboot. Assuming that's what you want for your businessman, make it a verb: The businessman clip-clopped across the linoleum floor, his footsteps echoing down the hallway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With respect to women's heels, I have also seen *clicking* and *clacking* used. As a general term, I have heard *clatter* used, but only when it was a number of women in heels walking together.

According to [the OED](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/clack), *clack* is the correct term in this case:

> make or cause to make a sharp sound or series of such sounds as a result of a hard object striking another

The OED then goes on to use shoes (specifically, women's heels, but theoretically any shoe would be appropriate here, provided the shoes were hard-soled) in the prepositional phrase featuring the aforementioned word:

> He heard the sound of her heels clacking across flagstones.

Finally, [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/clack) notes that this is a sound midway between a click and a clunk.

Comment: Considering your avatar, not surprising you'd know synonyms for clopping ;)